# usar img en menu principal wordpress

Tags: wordpress, imagen, menú

Tengo la duda de saber si se puede hacer y es que en el menu principal de wordpress quiero que en la opcion del medio cambiar el texto por una img, en los ajustes de wordpress no he visto nada y no se si directamente habra que ir a algun archivo php

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco más a que te refieres con la expresión "la opción del medio"??

Comment: Al final metiendo otro menu hecho por mi y metiendolo en el header.php me ha funcionado, junto a una funcion javascript con scrollTop() he podido sacar lo que pedia. Si no me habia explicado bien lo que queria era que el menu horizontal desapareciera cuando se hiciera scroll y apareciera solo el logo de la empresa y al darle click en el logo que se desplegase el menu verticalmente